# Google Sheets Filter by numerous substrings

Tags: regex, google-sheets

So, I currently have a pivot table that I'm trying to manipulate. In the B column, I have a list of names that start with a number and a letter. Example: "7A Kat Williams". What I'm trying to do, is filter the entire column to only show names (strings) that contain 4s or 5s (4A-E & 5A-E). I've been spinning my wheels for two days now and can't find a solution.

In the custom formula, I have tried `=regexmatch(B3:B;"4|5")` and that doesn't work. Thoughts?

[Dummy Copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SeR0fGnzsN62PDbQV_ST2REr4761YF29-ESNcxBBhNc/edit)

[Image of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9HY.png)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Sadly, no. When I use that it hides the entire column. The issue persists Wiktor.

Comment: Is there not a different filter for the classes (I'm assuming that's what the 4A-E 5A-E are)? It looks like your regex got applied to the scores (I can see only 5's showing and from the totals, it doesn't look like there are 4's)

Comment: Sorry, forgot the quantifier: `regexmatch(B3:B;"[^45]*[45].*")`

Comment: Sorry Jerry, but no. The name contains the class because of the output from a form. Long story short, only the student info column contains the class.

Comment: [Something like this maybe?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpOte.png) (I used `=or(isnumber(find(4,B2)),isnumber(find(5,B2)))`). Also trying the formula `=regexmatch(B2,"[45]")` and `=regexmatch(B2,"4|5")` work similarly

Comment: Hey Jerry, I tried all three and it still doesn't work correctly. It won't even save it as a custom formula.

Comment: can you share a copy/dummy of your sheet?

Comment: Player0  here is a dummy version as requested: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SeR0fGnzsN62PDbQV_ST2REr4761YF29-ESNcxBBhNc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In an attempt to make it easier I have altered the "Student Information". Now each name is like so... Example: "8C Jorge Washington". I have also made the change on the dummy form.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a solution](https://www.useloom.com/share/ddf21c8af0504d4f9388ca6cf3e474b9) but it might not work for all case scenarios so let me know if that is enough for you because you might need something else, and there is a lot of ways in which you can accomplish that goal.

> Basically what you do is to add a filter and then select manually the numbers
>   you want to appear.

Comment: Thank you for the video. That was my first thought, but it needs to automate itself. Since this list auto-populates it would be nice to just have the form figure it out on its own.

If I want it to do it automatically, how would I go about it?

Comment: Then you might want to go ahead and use a formula, for this case QUERY seems to be the best one. Have you tried it already?

Comment: There is a dummy copy of the form at the top. Wouldn't Query only offer true or false as output? How would you write it?